# Do people actually finish Xanth?

Tags: play-time

Referring to this game:

https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/4470/xanth

It's been a long while ago, but I remember that the few times my gaming group tried to play, we *never* finished a game.

Players who are near to winning must announce it, and players are allowed to interfere directly with each other.  So of course the other players gang up on the soon-to-be-winner and kill him.

That player then starts afresh as a new character, helping to beat down the next player who gets close to winning.  And so on.

Eventually we all just gave up.  Do people actually *win* this game, in a reasonable amount of time?

Comment: I think you should be asking if people finish the game not if the win. Also what do you consider a reasonable amount of time and how long do you play before you give up? From what I have seen online a game can take over 3 hours which may be fine for some but not for others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have been playing it wrong, it's harder to "gang up" on someone about to complete their quest than you make it sound.

By the rules each of the current player's opponents can put forward one hazard (so up to 5) but the current player chooses one of these hazards to face:

> After a brief period of bluster and agonizing over decisions that should be easy, each opponent may choose one hazard from his hand and place it face down in front of him. The player than chooses one of these cards for his party to encounter.

It sounds like you were having each player put forth a hazard and having the winning player face ALL of them. The only time you have to face multiple hazards is when opponents were playing multiple area specific hazards:

> As other opponents are agonizing over which hazards to play, an opponent with a hazard specific to the player's region can simply plop it onto the table face up, giving the player no choice and saving some agonizing on the part of the other opponents. If two or more players plop out hazards containing the designated region, the player must encounter each of them in turn, starting with the first one played.

Not all of these hazards would stop someone from winning - mostly that would be creature hazards - and even then the winning player would need to lose the fight having all their Chair Actors Xonked Out before they vanquish all the creatures.